# How can I prove this sequence convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove the sequence $(u_n)$ so that $u_1=1$ and $u_{n+1}=1+\dfrac{1}{u_n}$ is convergent. With some first items, I guess that the subsequence $(u_{2n})$ is decreasing and the subsequence $(u_{2n-1})$ is increasing, but I can't proof this. How can I proof?

Comment: You are dealing with the sequence of the convergents of the continued fraction of the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1+\frac{1}{\varphi}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We can write
$$u_{3} = 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{u_1}} = 1 + \frac{u_1}{u_1+1} = 
\frac{u_1+1}{u_1+1} + \frac{u_1}{u_1+1}
= \frac{2u_1+1}{u_1+1}$$

$$u_{4} = 1+\frac{u_1+1}{2u_1+1} = 
\frac{2u_1+1}{2u_1+1} + \frac{u_1+1}{2u_1+1} =
\frac{3u_1+2}{2u_1+1}$$
$$u_{5} = 1 + \frac{2u_1+1}{3u_1+2} =
\frac{3u_1+2}{3u_1+2} + \frac{2u_1+1}{3u_1+2} = 
 \frac{5u_1+3}{3u_1+2}$$
Notice a pattern? You can prove it using induction!

Comment: Nơ I can't see genal formula to proof by induction.

Comment: You see that it is the Fibonacci numbers, right? What I'm doing in each of these cases is expanding the $1$ as the denominator of the other fraction. I guess I'll elaborate with an extra step.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, you can simplify the proof with some loss of generality using $u_1=1$. Does this edit clear things up?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

First, solve your recurrence for its limit by writing $L=1+\frac 1L$.  Now you can look at the distance from $L$ by writing 
$$u_{k+1}-L=1+\frac 1{(u_k-L)+L}-L$$
and note that if $u_k \lt L, u_{k+1} \gt L$ and vice versa.  This shows the even terms are bounded below by $L$ and the odd terms are bounded above by $L$.
Now plug the definition for $u_k$ in terms of $u_{k-1}$ into the above and show the distance on the left is decreasing toward zero for the even terms and increasing toward zero for the odd terms.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show another possible approach.

Consider $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$. $f$ is clearly decreasing.

Thus $f \circ f$ is increasing.

We also have $u_1=1$, $u_2 = 2$, $u_3 = \frac{3}{2} > u_1$ and $u_4 = \frac{5}{3} < u_2$.

Since $u_{n+2} = f(f(u_n))$ it's very easy to see (by induction and using $f \circ f$ increasing) that $u_1 < u_3 < u_5 < \ldots$ and that $u_2 > u_4 > u_6 > \ldots$!

Let's call $\varphi = \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$ the fixed point of $f$. Again by induction on $n$, it's easy to verify that $u_{2n+1} < \varphi < u_{2n}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now because of boundness in the right direction both $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ converge. Let's call $l$ and $m$ the two limits. We have (since $u_{n+1} = f(u_n)$ and $f$ is continuous) $l = f(m)$ and $m = f(l)$.

Thus $lm = l+1$ and $lm = m+1$. So $l=m$ and $l= \varphi$.

Therefore the sequence converges to $\varphi$

Comment: I can' find general formulas of u_2n and u_2n-1. Can you help me?